# Do all mammals have a Ventricular system?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, zoology

I am familiar with the human Ventricular system that circulates Cerebrospinal fluid. This is needed among other reasons, to suspend the heavy human brain, and for injury protection. Do all mammals have a need a Ventricular system?

Maybe some did not have as strong of an evolutionary need for cerebrospinal fluid?

Comment: Are you asking `Do all animals...` as in your title or `do all mammals...` as in your post. Note that after asking `do all mammals...` in your post you are asking `For example don't woodpeckers...`, while woodpeckers are obviously not mammals. Note that many animals don't have a circulatory system nor a brain (such as [jellyfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jellyfish) for example) and so the answer to the question in the title is `no`.

Comment: Of course not. For the human primates, nearly most of them have the ventrcular system, but for the non-human primates, seldom of them get.

Comment: Just mammals then. I forgot about jellyfish. Which are such a great exception to so many attempts at generalizing the kingdom of animals.

Comment: A reiteration of the initial question based on the exclusion of jellyfish as invertebrates: *How might the evolutionary development of the ventricular system coincide with a functional separation of the central and peripheral nervous systems?*

Answer (score 2):

The ventricular system is common to vertebrates. It's also necessary for brain nutrition, assists in preventing under/over perfusion by exerting/releasing pressure, and forms part of the brain's glymphatic clearance pathway.

**See also:**

[Totally Tubular: The Mystery behind Function and Origin of the Brain Ventricular System](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3003255/)